# what should be size of same image on different imageviews in my app?

Tags: android, image, image-size

User profile image is being shown on different imageviews in my app.

//full screen 
[image]

// in grid
[image]

//as a thumbnail
[image]

I am thinking of generating copy of image for every situation. 
What should be ideal size for every case? (min and max)

Should I store my images in database or in file system? (server)

Comment: You could follow the Google design guidelines, for instance.

Comment: If you use a vector graphic, then one image should scale to all sizes

Comment: vector drawable is the least painful option. Your image appears in a lot of sizes throughout the app and can be scaled up/down by the system on different screen size too.

Comment: Now there're 2 cases: If your images are stored on a server (user uploaded), it's the backend job to pre-process the original image, scale into multiple size (small/normal/large ...), then the app call and get the right image for each case by different URL. If it's local only, better use `VectorDrawable`.

Comment: first you should store your images on server so that later you can change without recompiling the app for any image update , secondly you can use library like glide to load images , thirdly the size should not be too small ( it will display blurry ) or too big ( will create oom exception ) , if you using library like glide its better to use same image since it will cache and show later time , but if you want to go for specific size it will be hit and trial , according to me 128x128 for thumb and 400x400 for big one will do...

Comment: 128x128 for thumb and 400x400 for big

....and full screen?

Answer (score 0):

you can simply set the scaleType of your imageView to centerInside: (in your xml file)

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Comment: I believe the OP is asking option for the size of the original image, not how the `ImageView` scale it in the app

Comment: @TamHuynh Yes but I think if he scale the image properly the imageView shows the image in a proper way (for example in second image in grids). maybe it helps!